# why use mixed-based replication for mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

I am in the process of configuring MySQL replication and am intending to use row-based-replication but I was also reading up about mixed-based replication.

This is where statement-based is the default and then for certain circumstances (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-mixed.html) MySQL will switch to row-based.

The list is quit vast on when it will switch to row-based.

My questions are:

Does any one use mixed?
If yes why did you chose this over just using one or the other?

Thanks in advance

Comment: MIXED would be useful in this case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057593/warning-unsafe-statement-written-to-the-binary-log-using-statement-format-since

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does any one use mixed?

I bet many people have used Mixed-mode replication, since this was the default for a long time according to the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html):

> From MySQL 5.1.12 to MySQL 5.1.28, mixed format is the default. Beginning with MySQL 5.1.29, statement-based format is the default.

The [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/06/debugging-problems-with-row-based-replication/) talks about different problems with the different replication methods.

So, it seems that MySQL has been trying to switch between mixed-mode, statement-based and row-based replication within the 5.1.x series, and that is unnerving.

I'm currently reading [High Performance MySQL, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718) from O'Reilly. It has a great chapter on replication, and is well worth the read. Many of my questions have been answered with an hour of reading. You can read some of the chapter in [Chapter 8. Replication > Replication Under the Hood - Pg. 357](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596101718/replication_under_the_hood):

> Because neither format is perfect for every situation, MySQL 5.1 switches between
>   statement-based and row-based replication dynamically. By default, it uses
>   statement-based replication, but when it detects an event that cannot be replicated
>   correctly with a statement, it switches to row-based replication. You can also control
>   the format as needed by setting the binlog_format session variable.